# Getting errors when using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm doing a tutorial on rspec and keep getting errors whenever I try to perform rake tests or run rspec manually through the terminal. Here's what I get:

```
mes-mbp:00_hello Me$ ls
hello.rb    hello_spec.rb   index.html
mes-mbp:00_hello Me$ rspec 00_hello/hello_spec.rb
/Users/Me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `block in requires='
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `each'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `requires='
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:110:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `each'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `process_options_into'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: More information on what I'm doing as requested:
I'm following along with [this](http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby) tutorial. In the code above I'm trying to run tests on the hello.rb file that are in the hello_spec.rb file which has the 'require hello' code in it.

Comment: Can you post some more information abut what you are doing?

Comment: `touch spec_helper.rb`

Comment: I don't see a `spec_helper` file at all. This does not even look like a rails app. Sinatra maybe? You also look like you need to run `rspec --init` at the root of your project. This will create files like `spec_helper`. [See Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted) for more info.

Comment: Those tutorials are pretty badly out of date - I would recommend something like https://www.codeschool.com/courses/testing-with-rspec. You definitely don´t want to get started with RSpec 2 and then have to learn the new RSpec 3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving RSpec the wrong path to your spec file.

The current working directory is `00_hello`.

```
mes-mbp:00_hello Me$ rspec 00_hello/hello_spec.rb
```

Will cause RSpec to look for `00_hello\00_hello\hello_spec.rb`.

If you have run `rspec --init` may have a `.rspec` file which will require `spec_helper.rb` if it contains the line:

```
--require spec_helper
```

The most common practice when writing specs is to place specs in a directory named `spec`. That way you can run all the project specs by

```
 $ rspec specs
```

#### Added:

This is a very common structure for gems and other ruby projects:

```
lib/
   hello.rb
spec/
   spec_helper.rb
   hello_spec.rb
```

Its so common that RSpec will add the `/lib` and `/spec` directory to the load path automatically.

So you can do:

```
# spec/hello_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'lib/hello' # instead of a relative path! Wehoo.

RSpec.describe Hello do
  # ...
end
```